# VirtuaWin - Show window on 2 out of 4 Desktops

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop, virtual-desktop-manager, virtuawin

Is there a way to configure VirtuaWin (http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) so that a window is displayed on more than 1 desktop, but not on all of them?  For example I want to show Visual Studio on Desktop 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4.

Or could I set it up that a program is shown only on Row 1, but not Row 2 or Row 3?

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Comment: [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/?id=features#customization) does this, if you're looking for an alternative to VirtuaWin.

Comment: @laggingreflex - How do you set this up in Dexpot

Comment: In the [rules](http://dexpot.de/gfx/rules_en.png) you can specify multiple actions like move to desktop 1, move to desktop 2. Or something like that, been a while since I used it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/). You may be interested in trying out an alternative called [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de). This [program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program) is free for non-commercial use.

In [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de):

1. Right click on the [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de) icon in your taskbar
2. Click "Desktop Rules"
3. Click on "Assistant"
4. Name the rule
5. Click "Next"
6. In "Condition 1" fill all the required fields (for example: Executable is [firefox](http://getfirefox.com).[exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe))
7. In Action 1, choose "Copy" and then "Desktop 1"
8. Click "Add"
9. In Action 2, choose "Copy" and then "Desktop 2"
10. Click "Done"
11. Click on the newly created rule and check if "Apply rule automatically" is selected, if not select it.
12. Now restart [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de).